# Will fluentlenium pom.xml dependncy download all dependancies that it requires?

Tags: maven, selenium, dependency-injection, pom.xml, fluentlenium

I am new to maven and dependency world. 
So I am changing my fluentlenium version of 0.10.2 to 0.10.9

pom.xml of test suite

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluentlenium-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I looked in maven repo
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fluentlenium/fluentlenium-core/0.10.9

I see it is using selenium 2.48.2 as a compile dependency. But when I check in my  project external library , I still see 2.41 selenuium , which is for old(0.10.2) version.

So do I have to download selenium 2.48.2 manually or fluentlenium should download all dependency when you do install?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hmm.  Take a look at Selenide instead of FluentLenium.  Its a similar project but more mature IMHO.

Comment: @djangofan I am looking at Selenide documentations. Looks great. But as of right now I still have to use FluentLenium for my current project.